# How to reload a page in ionic 4 using Router?

Tags: angular, ionic4

I want to reload a page component from another component using router.

I tired to reload the page by below workaround. It is working but it is not much efficient.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/SampleComponent', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>{
    this.router.navigate([page]);
});
```

Do we have any other approach to reload a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to reload the pages on navigating to the same URL then you can use this configuration under your root module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
       ...
       RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})
       ....

   ],
  declarations: [ ... ],
  bootstrap:    [ ... ]
})
```

You don't need to go to another componenent and navigate back to the same, just use:

```
this.router.navigate([page]);
```

`skipLocationChange` which you are using will prevent a new url to be pushed to browsers history so that if you press back, it doesn't go the temporary route you are navigating.